# query after passing parameter

Tags: jasper-reports

I was wondering how to redefine a *JasperReports* report sub data set query from *Java* code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the default values of all parameters in IReport query window and then try to run the query again.

Default format for dates:

```
 new  Date(111,3,1)           for -2011-Apr-01
```

and for today date:-

```
new  java.util.Date()        for Today's date
```

Comment: I dont know what will be the default value for a DATE/TIME Field. please give me some examples

Comment: Thanks a lot Sharad. Even in the query window im getting correct values pulled up from the DB  but when i give preview it fails again during the report generation .. Is it a bug ?

Comment: Could you copy the "Report Output" when you run report in Ireport. To copy this go to "Window" option in Ireport then select "Report Output".

Comment: Compiling to file... C:\Users\Sadagopan\Documents\smbdbFinal.jasper
Compilation running time: 879! 
  Filling report...
  Locale: English (India)
  Time zone: Default
Setting up the file resolver...  
Report fill running time: 97! (pages generated: 1) 
  Viewing with JasperReports Viewer
Export running time: 1!

Comment: Added Screen shots for your reference